# Call Log and SMS permissions. This policy will impact one or more of your apps.

Tags: permissions, sms, policy

our app flash alert  use RECEIVE_SMS  permission to make flash when user receive an sms . we received yesterday an email from google " October, we announced updates to our Permissions policy that will limit which apps are allowed to request Call Log and SMS permissions. This policy will impact one or more of your apps.....

Affected apps

Affected apps and permissions are listed below, up to 20; if you have additional apps, please ensure that they are also compliant with the Permissions policy.

com.***.flash.sms.***   RECEIVE_SMS  ...."

what is the solution to avoid using this permission wen need only to detect if an sms is received to blink flashlight ?

Answer (score 0):

Google Play restricts the use of [high risk or sensitive permissions](https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security-deception/permissions/), including the [SMS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission_group#SMS) or [Call Log](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission_group#CALL_LOG) permission groups.

If your app does not require access to Call Log or SMS permissions, you must remove these permissions from your app's manifest. Details on policy compliant alternative implementation are also detailed below.

If you believe your app meets the policy requirements for acceptable use or is eligible for an exception, submit a Permissions Declaration Form as soon as possible for Google Play to review. You will be notified if your request has been approved. You do not need to have implemented APK changes in order to submit the Declaration Form.

Apps that fail to meet policy requirements or submit a Permissions Declaration Form by January 9, 2019 may be removed from Google Play.

For apps with Declaration Forms submissions received by Jan 9, 2019, Google Play, at its option, may grant extensions until March 9, 2019 for you to make changes to bring your app(s) into compliance with this Play policy. If you do not plan on using these permissions, but still require additional time to bring your app(s) into compliance, please complete the [Declaration Form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfCnRaa4b1VuHhE4gVekWJc_V0Zt4XiTlsKsTipTlPg5ECA7Q/viewform).

Source : [GOOGLE Use of SMS or Call Log permission groups](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9047303)